# Fillna in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

The code below is executing correctly:

```
data['Native Country'].fillna(data['Native Country'].mode()**[0]**, inplace=True)
```

Can anyone explain what [0] indicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**mode()** method returns Series/DataFrame.

Check [https://pandas.py.....as.Series.mode.html#pandas.Series.mode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html#pandas.Series.mode)    for Series & [https://panda......i/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html) for DataFrame.

In your case, it returns Series object (as you are performing it on Series) even if there is a single value in Series.

Using **[0]** means we want to access the first value/item in the Series for replacement of null values.

Have a look at http://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/mode-function-python-pandas-dataframe-row-column-wise-mode/.

This might help you a lot.